# Using Object Reader function to read till end of file

Tags: java

I am trying to read the objects written in a file.

```
ObjectInputStream objectInputStream=new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("D:\\Users\\Dell-7560\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Advanced Computer Networking\\src\\Experiment8\\Packets.txt"));
        Packet p = new Packet();
        while((p=(Packet) objectInputStream.readObject())!=null)
        {
            p.printDetails();
        }
```

This is the output I acheive.

```
Packet Weight : 1
Packet Data : stibulum in neque ne
Packet time value 1522079495482
Packet Weight : 2
Packet Data :  libero mattis hendr
Packet time value 1522079495482
Packet Weight : 3
Packet Data : rit in nec quam.
Packet time value 1522079495482
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2626)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1321)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
    at Experiment8.CreateDummyData.main(CreateDummyData.java:69)
C:\Users\Dell-7560\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

How to read the file without the exception. i.e. till end of file using the object reader funtion.

Comment: Place your media queries at the end of your css file

Comment: gave the requirement part to show what I wanted to do, not what you have to do.

Comment: I tried that Izzy, It still does not work.

Comment: Do you have your `<meta>` viewport set?

Comment: Yes I have added the <meta> tag.

Comment: @Boaz I have edited my question w.r.t to your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the ":" from below line:

```
@media screen and  (min-width: 992px) // It should like this now
@media screen and  (min-width : : 992px) // It was before like that (: :) should not twice only single (:)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was actually helpful.

Answer (score 2):

```
/**********For Desktop *************/ 
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {}

/**********For Tablet *************/
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {}

/**********For Mobile *************/
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {}
```

You have added (::) two semicolon in media query, just remove that.

Also put this in the head tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was actually helpful.